# Useless popular tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I found [this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info) on Stack Overflow.

Whoever created or edited the tag had said specifically ***not*** to use it. What is the point of the tag then?

It has quite a few questions on it, which some are very well 
received. Should we delete this tag?

I asked this question on Meta because there might be similar tags on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It's actually wrong, since there are edge cases to use the company name, but they are rare.